# Angular 5 GET REST Api with Authorization return stuts 500 Internal Error (from client)

Tags: angular, rest, tone-analyzer

I'm consuming tone analyser api from IBM Watson tools. As testing it by postman it's working fine, but in Angular it return error as 500 status. As tone analyser api it requires authorization which I put credentials into headers.

Here is sample of my code.

service.ts:

```cpp
const TONE_API = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&text=";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ************************:************'
  })
};
const options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();
options.headers = httpOptions.headers;

@Injectable()
export class ToneAnalyserService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // API: GET /message
  getAnalyser(message:string) {
    let url = TONE_API + message;
    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(err=>{
        throw(err);
      });
  }
```

component.ts:

```cpp
 this.message = "I like this idea!"; 
   this.toneAnalyser.getAnalyser(this.message).subscribe(res =>{
     this.result = res;
       console.log(res.json());
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: Why are you setting access control headers on the client side? Does the error come with any additional explanation (e.g. in the body)?

Comment: Yes as you see, I put 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' into headers

Comment: I do see that you did, I'm asking *why*. Those headers are for *responses*, not requests; they're set by the server, not the client.

Comment: Oh, cause I can't edit code on the server cause I'm using external api. So I'm searching for alternatives on the client side. What should I edit on code to make it work ?

Comment: You can't fix that in the client code. CORS needs to be implemented on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do direct calls to `watsonplatform` from browser application due to CORS. 
`watsonplatform` doesn't support that policy.

You have to create your own backend service, which will proxy your requests.

**OR:**

For local development you can create [proxy.config.js](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/) alias:

```
module.exports = {
  '/watsonplatform': {
    target: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },
};
```

and make calls from application like `get('/watsonplatform/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&text=')`

When you will host your application use nginx aliases to do the same thing.

Comment: I edited the code as you recommended and it returns 404 not found. More details are in the post's answer. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you have to edit start script in package.json also, "start": "ng serve --open --proxy-config proxy.config.js". After that rerun application via npm run start

Comment: please, join the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179190/angular-5-get-rest-api-with-authorization-return-stuts-500-internal-error-from-c

Answer (score 0):

I did config the proxy and set Api like you said. Meanwhile, I edited the code and tried to call the route but it returns url 404 not found in the console.

```cpp
GET http://localhost:4200/watsonplatform/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&text=I%27m%20happy 404 (Not Found)
```

The sample is below:

```cpp
baseUrl ="/watsonplatform/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&text=";

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toneAnalyser: ToneAnalyserService,
  private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic fc52487b-f8e5-4948-a11c-43901c0b6a0d:NsP8HyWsoLw8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'       
      })
    };

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"I'm happy",options).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to edit start script in package.json also,  `"start": "ng serve --open --proxy-config proxy.config.js"`. After that rerun application via `npm run start`